# How to use Textbox to enter value and set in memory?

Tags: c#

```
var input = textBox2.Text;

var bytes = input.Split('0x').Select(i => i.Trim()).Select(i => Convert.ToByte(i, 16)).ToArray();
PS3.SetMemory(0x00D5B250, bytes);
```

I'm trying to be able to put bytes in this format 0x63CB23B076B55C2E only, but have it remove the "0x" out of it, then set it to memory as I have shown. But I get an error when I try this.

Comment: can you please rephrase? it's very unclear what you're asking

Comment: I want to be able to put this 0x63CB23B076B55C2E in a textbox and it remove the 0x in the beginning

Comment: you want the hex to be converted to decimal?

Comment: I just want to be able to enter 0x63CB23B076B55C2E in the textbox and have it only read this part 63CB23B076B55C2E

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)